# How i can avoiding refresh the script if i click button

Tags: streamlit

“I am facing an issue with my script and I’m unsure of how to resolve it. My application is designed to perform a simple task of scanning a barcode and matching it with the barcodes stored in my data. When a match is found, the application should display the minimum stock level. To achieve this, I have incorporated a button that triggers the barcode scanning function. Once the button is clicked, the application scans and checks for a match.”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLE8k.png)
2. the app show this interface
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdAta.png)

the probleme is if i click + or - or valid in seconde interface the script is re run again and

```
import pymongo
import streamlit as st 
from pymongo import MongoClient
import cv2
from pyzbar import pyzbar

# Connexion à la base de données MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

# Sélection de la base de données et de la collection
db = client["database"]
PDR = db["PDR"]


st.set_page_config( layout="wide")
st.title('Magasine de les Pieces de Rechange')


if st.button('scanner') :
    # Capture d'une seule image de la caméra
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Recherche des codes-barres dans l'image
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

    # Boucle sur les codes-barres trouvés
    for barcode in barcodes:
        # Extraction des informations du code-barres
        barcode_data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcode_type = barcode.type

        # Affichage des informations du code-barres
        print("Type de code-barres:", barcode_type)
        print("Données du code-barres:", barcode_data)

        # Libération des ressources
        cap.release()

        st.write(barcode_data)

        DataCodeBar = PDR.find_one({'CodeBar': str(barcode_data)})
        if DataCodeBar:
            col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 = st.columns(7)
            col3.metric("MinStock", str(DataCodeBar['MinStock']))
            col5.metric("Stockinitial", str(DataCodeBar['Stockinitail']))
            number = col1.number_input('Insert a number', step = 1)
            if col2.button('Valide'):
                if DataCodeBar is not None:
                    new_stock = int(DataCodeBar['stockactuel']) - number
                    col4.metric("StockActuel", str(new_stock), delta=(-1)*number)
                    PDR.update_one(DataCodeBar, {"$set" : {"stock-actuel" : new_stock}})
            col6.metric("code KEN", str(DataCodeBar['CodeBar']))
            col7.metric("place", str(DataCodeBar['place']))
        else:
            st.write('Ce produit n\'existe pas dans la base de données.')
```

i tried this code but nothing

```
import pymongo
import streamlit as st 
from pymongo import MongoClient
import cv2
from pyzbar import pyzbar

# Connexion à la base de données MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

# Sélection de la base de données et de la collection
db = client["database"]
PDR = db["PDR"]


st.set_page_config( layout="wide")
st.title('Magasine de les Pieces de Rechange')

if "boolean" not in st.session_state :
    st.session_state.boolean = False

def callback() :
    st.session_state.boolean = True

if st.button('scanner', on_click = callback or st.session_state.boolean) :
    # Capture d'une seule image de la caméra
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Recherche des codes-barres dans l'image
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

    # Boucle sur les codes-barres trouvés
    for barcode in barcodes:
        # Extraction des informations du code-barres
        barcode_data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcode_type = barcode.type

        # Affichage des informations du code-barres
        print("Type de code-barres:", barcode_type)
        print("Données du code-barres:", barcode_data)

        # Libération des ressources
        cap.release()

        st.write(barcode_data)

        DataCodeBar = PDR.find_one({'CodeBar': str(barcode_data)})
        if DataCodeBar:
            col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 = st.columns(7)
            col3.metric("MinStock", str(DataCodeBar['MinStock']))
            col5.metric("Stockinitial", str(DataCodeBar['Stockinitail']))
            number = col1.number_input('Insert a number', step = 1, on_change= callback or st.session_state.boolean)
            if col2.button('Valide', on_click= callback or st.session_state.boolean):
                if DataCodeBar is not None:
                    new_stock = int(DataCodeBar['stockactuel']) - number
                    col4.metric("StockActuel", str(new_stock), delta=(-1)*number)
                    PDR.update_one(DataCodeBar, {"$set" : {"stock-actuel" : new_stock}})
            col6.metric("code KEN", str(DataCodeBar['CodeBar']))
            col7.metric("place", str(DataCodeBar['place']))
        else:
            st.write('Ce produit n\'existe pas dans la base de données.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit inherently reloads the application upon widget interaction.  One solution you can use would be to move the "+" and "-" buttons inside of a form and then create a submit button that handles form submition.

```
import streamlit as st

with st.form("my_form"):
   st.write("Inside the form")
   number = st.number_input('Insert a number', step = 1)

   # Every form must have a submit button.
   submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
   if submitted:
       st.write("slider", slider_val, "checkbox", checkbox_val)

       if st.button('Valide'):
            # insert additional logic here
```